# SwiftUI: fullScreenCover equivalent for macOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I am writing a cross-platform SwiftUI app that needs to present a password prompt if the user wishes to "lock" the application.  The lock screen should cover all views in the application until the user successfully authenticates.  On iOS I'm able to do this using the `fullScreenCover` method like this:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLocked, content: {
        ApplicationLockView(viewModel: ApplicationLockViewModel())
    })
```

This works great.  However, this method is unavailable on macOS.  Is there an equivalent way of accomplishing this on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fullScreenCover(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)` does support in **Mac Catalyst** 14.0+.

Enable the mac support for the target:

[image]

Source used for testing on mac:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            ModalView()
        }
    }
}
struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

**Using Move Edge Transition:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Present", action: {
                withAnimation(.linear) {
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
                }
            })
            
            if isPresented {
                ModalView(isPresented: self.$isPresented).transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            VStack {
                Button("Dismiss",action: {
                    withAnimation(.linear) {
                        self.isPresented.toggle()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had preferred not to go down the Catalyst route, as it makes the app look and feel more like an iPad app than a native macOS app.  If I enable Catalyst just to get this one feature, what are the ramifications?  Will it continue to behave like a macOS app?  Or will it default to iPad behavior?

Comment: It feels like a mac app, as the option `Optimize Interface for Mac` replaces controls with the macOS counterpart. If you want to go with the multiplatform route, it's going to be more complex as so many modifiers are not available on macOS.